# Check user input values with predetermined picklist and replace any typos

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to write a vba code when run can review through a column and validate whether all user input values matches a preset array of accepted values. Those values that are wrong will be highlighted.

Not sure if it's also possible to replace typos and wrong letter case with the array of preset values?

Thanks much in advance.

Below is something that I have tried to reference online and tailored for my use case but it is not working. When I ran the code, the wrong values are not identified.

Comment: It looks like you may have forgotten to include the code? Also, I believe you will find "trying to fix typos" a very challenging task.

Comment: couldn't you use data validation in the cells where the users would input values?

Comment: **(a)** You should use data validation against a lookup list. **(b)** If your sheet has already invalid data, use conditional formatting (use for example `VLookup` to check if a value exists) **(c)** Forget about automatic correction. This is really tricky, and there is a reason that there exist so many jokes about auto correction.